Is Testing on Sepolia Enough for L2 Chains, or Are There Better Practices?
I’m working on a dApp that interacts with Uniswap's swap router contract, and I’m targeting L2 networks like Arbitrum and Polygon. During testing, I noticed that in the Uniswap UI, only the Ethereum Sepolia testnet and Unichain are available. This raised a few questions:

Is testing on Sepolia sufficient for L2 chains, given that they share EVM compatibility?
How do developers usually handle testing when there’s no visible liquidity on testnets like Arbitrum Sepolia?
Are there alternative practices or tools to simulate or test swaps effectively in such scenarios?

